How to create a boundary automatically around points
I created origin-destination networks in ArcGIS Pro manually using the HOW TO Create connection lines between points and a line in ArcGIS Pro tutorial. Green point is the origin and brown point is the destination (Refer to the image).
Now I want to create a boundary around each origin-destination network but how do I automate the process or make the process faster?
I don't want to draw it manually.


Would you like to connect green points around individual browns?

@FelixP Yes and I already done that (Refer to the image). Now I want to create a boundary around them

Would you like to connect green points to each other, so line goes around individual browns?

@FelixIP Something like that would be ok.  Or a polygon around individual browns without connecting green points to each other

Make sure your green points and connections share common ID field (say PART) with brown points. Define shortest link length (L) in each group and draw buffer around parent brown point with slightly smaller radius than L or simply very small buffer:

Find intersection points between buffer outline and connections, convert to single parts. Find script that assigns chainage to points on the line:

Using spatial join twice transfer chainage from intersection points->connection->green points.
Now you can use points to line tool (line ID = PART) and chainage as sort field to connect green points by closed line:

Note 'bad' polygons 1 and 3. Either fix them by hand by adding brown point as extra vertex or append such brown points to green points making sure that their chainage is 1mm greater than largest one in a group (or equal to 0.0) and re-run points to line tool.
Not sure that you can convert them to polygons at once due to intersections.
